# How to retrieve blog posts by label using blogger API by using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I using blogger api in my react app to integrate blogger content with it by using the fetch APIs, as a JSON's objects.

I need to retrieve/filter posts by a label.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const bloggerUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/5039479718685240371/posts?callback=handleResponse&key=AIzaSyDxfWmXTRnO5yIp25NvuUEBWKSa_5mqjHA";

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
   bloggerWithFetch();
  }, []);

  const bloggerWithFetch = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(bloggerUrl);
   const jsonData = await response.json();
   setUserData(jsonData);
    };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <p>{userData.content}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```